# Python connection to QuickBooks Online

Tags: python-3.x, api, quickbooks-online

I tried several options to connect to QuickBooks API 3. and tried to follow steps on doc. But I'm still blocked on the step bellow. How can I have a token. As I did not received anything from QBO ? thanks for helping me to continue my code.
I can see auth_url but don't know what to do after...
thanks

```
from intuitlib.client import AuthClient
from intuitlib.enums import Scopes
from flask import Flask,redirect
import QBOConnector

#Instantiate client
auth_client = AuthClient(
    QBOConnector.CLIENT_ID,
    QBOConnector.CLIENT_SECRET,
    QBOConnector.REDIRECT_URI,
    QBOConnector.environment, # “sandbox” or “production”
)

# Prepare scopes
scopes = [
    Scopes.ACCOUNTING,
]

# Get authorization URL
auth_url = auth_client.get_authorization_url(scopes)

print(auth_url)

#Using standard redirect
test = redirect(auth_url)
```

My objective is to 
connection and having refresh_token and realm_ID

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to save this:

```
REDIRECT_URI = 'https://developer.intuit.com/v2/OAuth2Playground/RedirectUrl' # not using the redirection at the moment
ENV = QBOConnector.PROD_environment
REFRESH_TOKEN = QBOConnector.PROD_TOKEN # Refresh token needs to be added here (which will be generated from https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/playground)
COMPANY_ID = QBOConnector.PROD_COMPANY_ID #id of the company that we use in the example

# auth credentials to connect to the QBO account
auth_client = AuthClient(
        client_id = QBOConnector.PROD_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret = QBOConnector.PROD_CLIENT_SECRET,
        environment = ENV,
        redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI,
    )


# creating the client object to access the QBO account
client = QuickBooks(
        auth_client= auth_client,
        refresh_token= REFRESH_TOKEN,
        company_id= COMPANY_ID,
    )

# retrieving all customers for the above client object
customers = Customer.all(qb=client)

# printing all customer names on the console/shell
for customer in customers:
    print (customer)

# request authorization
auth_header = 'Bearer {0}'.format(auth_client.access_token)
headers = {
    'Authorization': auth_header,
    'Accept': 'application/json'
}

base_url = 'https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com'

# --- trial Balance
url = '{0}//v3/company/{1}/reports/TrialBalance?end_date=2019-09-30&minorversion=4'.format(base_url,
                                                                                           QBOConnector.PROD_COMPANY_ID)

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

this permits an acces to a Trial balance report for example.